# Finding median in mysql by using row num in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to find the median(consider lower half value for even count) of Salary values in MySQl. Table consists of a

```
Table Structure

ID
Salary
```

Since there is no rownum, I wrote the following code to generate rownum in Mysql.

```
set @r = 0;
Select 
    rownum, id, Salary
from
    (Select 
        @r:=@r + 1 as rownum, id, Salary
    from
        E
    order by Salary asc) p
where
    p.rownum = (Select 
            max(p.rownum)
        from
            p);
```

This won't work because most internal query runs first. Can anyone has a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, because MySQL processes the sub query before the outer query, you can do:

```
Where p.rownum * 2 in (@r, @r + 1)
```

Note:  your question doesn't calculate the median.  This is one method.

Comment: Yes, this worked.
@r will store the number of last entry. So whenever, median is encountered that time p.rownum will be equal to @r for even numbers (@r + 1 for odd numbers). Awesome work.

Comment: Can you modify this calculate the exact median? For even counts, median will be the mean of middle two rows.

Comment: @Parin . . . You should ask another question.  The "exact median" is not always well defined, so be sure that you include examples with an even number of records.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a derived table that was created in the outer query, in a sub query.

You can create the table and use it:

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_FOR_SELECT AS
Select @r:=@r+1 as rownum, id, Salary from E
order by Salary asc;

Select rownum, id, Salary
from TMP_FOR_SELECT p
where p.rownum = (Select max(t.rownum) from TMP_FOR_SELECT t);
```

**EDIT:** For the median salary, try this:

```
set @r = 0;
Select rownum, id, Salary from
(Select @r:=@r+1 as rownum, id, Salary from E
order by Salary asc) p
where p.rownum = ROUND((Select COUNT(*) from e)/2);
```

Comment: I do not want to create another table. Any other way to find the median?

Comment: I want the median salary, I know how to get the highest salary. Haha, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Your query is my question on this thread. This won't work because most internal query runs first. So table p is not defined while counting the rows.

Comment: @Parin That's a typo!.. wrote `P` instead of `E` , now.

Comment: Yes, this will work. But looking for something more neat.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no built-in function for calculating median in MySQL while solving a [hacker rank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-20/problem?isFullScreen=true) problem to find out the median, I was really got stuck, while searching and understanding the [concept of median](https://youtu.be/cc7ELv2_Xww), I got to this easy method to calculate the median in MySQL

```
   with cal_median as (
select*,
    row_number() over(order by column_name ) as rn,
    count(*) over() as rc
    from table_name
) 
select column_name from cal_median 
where rn in((rc+1)/2 ,(rc+2)/2);
```

- This is valid for both odd set of values and even set of values
- In case if you are using Oracle just use the built-in function

  select median(colum_name) from table_name